# WPF DataGrid SelectedItems not deselecting

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a DataGrid that has checkboxes that are bound to the items' `IsSelected` property. I'm trying to create a feature to allow you to select rows in the grid by click/dragging or click / shift click / ctrl clicking other rows, then right click > Select to set the `IsSelected` Property of my items. The checkboxes are working perfectly, properly two-way binding to my `IsSelected` property of my objects.

I've got it to 90%, but when I send the DataGrid's `SelectedItems` value, it sometimes sends items that *were* selected but aren't anymore.

I found the code to send the DataGrid's `SelectedItems` to the command [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/03b0b99e-67c6-4f3c-976f-6cded607c4ae/passing-the-datagridselecteditems-via-commandparameter?forum=wpf&prof=required)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Select" 
                      Command="{Binding Data.SelectCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItems,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

C# code from my viewmodel

```
private void Select(object selectedObjects)
{ 
    var items = (System.Collections.IList)selectedObjects;
    var collection = items.Cast<ItemType>().ToList();
    foreach (var item in collection)
        item.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Here's what I do to reproduce it.

Scenario 1:

1. The control loads, nothing is selected by default
2. I click and drag to select all options
3. Right click and choose `Select`
4. All the checkboxes are now set as checked, as expected
5. Click on the first row so only it is highlighted
6. Right click and choose `Deselect`
7. All row's checkboxes are deselected (wrong!)

Scenario 2:

1. Control loads, nothing is selected
2. Click and drag and select first 2 entries
3. Right Click and choose `Select`, checkboxes get checked
4. Uncheck rows 1 and 2
5. Select rows 4 and 5
6. Right Click > `Select`
7. Rows 1, 2, 4, and 5 are now checked. (wrong)
8. Uncheck 1, 2, 4, and 5
9. Select rows 7 and 8
10. Right Click > `Select`
11. Rows 1, 2, 7, and 8 are now checked. (just what.)

I'm finding it very hard to come up with some sort of consistent reason that it's acting this way. My best guess is that when I right click on the datagrid, it doesn't act as a normal selection operation. Anyone have any clues why this is happening, or how I can force the grid to properly select the rows I tell it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I am using a wrapping class to enable selection on my objects: `Selectable<T>`. This object contains an `IsSelected` bool and a `T Item`. The creator of this class had overridden the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. This was causing the equals checks to fail, so the DataGrid wasn't properly deselecting the objects because they were being detected as being different items.

The code in the question above should work correctly if you are doing proper `Equals` checks on your objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost using MVVM, but where is your ViewModel? With a ViewModel this becomes easy.

You have an Model object you are using for your DataSource: AccountJobList
It is a list of Model objects, which I assume is AccountJob.

So perhaps AccountJob doesn't have an IsChecked property or it does but it doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. That is why we create ViewModels.
So create an AccountJobViewModel that is a wrapper to AccountJob. This AccountJobViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Now in our ViewModel we add an IsChecked property.

Now we create an AccountJobListViewModel that inherits ObservableCollection (or `List<AccountJobViewModel>` if you don't need your collection to be Observable). AccountJobListViewModel takes in an AccountJobList and foreach AccountJob in the list, it creates an AccountJobViewModel and adds it to the collection.

You also need a property for SelectedItems in either the AccountJobListViewModel or its parent. I assume your Select/Deselect methods are in a ViewModel of some sort, so perhaps it goes there.

Now you simply bind IsChecked on your ViewModel.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```

Now in your code, you simply set each selected AccountJobViewModel's IsChecked property to true.

```
private void Select(object selectedObjects)
{
  foreach (AccountJobViewModel item in SelectedItems)
    item.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very explicit, I was trying to be concise. I have a viewmodel, the C# code above is from the viewmodel. The checkbox is properly binding to the IsSelected properties of my objects, that's not the issue.

Comment: What I would LIKE to do is to have another object in my viewmodel that is bound to the SelectedItems property of the DataGrid, and then my Select method can simple look at that list, but it doesn't let me bind to the SelectedItems property. This is why I'm trying to send the DataGrid's SelectedItems as a parameter to the Select Command / Method

Comment: I think i accidentally clicked edit on your answer instead of my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Found the issue. It was some weird thing in the object I was using. You got me on the right track to finding the issue though!